# fluentd output json value as json without message_key

Tags: fluentd

I'm creating a log pipeline with filtering, transformations and multiple output routes.

I have a problem with outputing the raw log (without the "message_key").

Currently, the log looks like:

```
{"log": {"type": "debug", "log" :"This is the log message" , <More Entries>} }
```

I would like to drop the "log" message_key and output:

```
{"type": "debug", "log" :"This is the log message", <More Entries>}
```

I've tried:

1.

```
<filter *>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  <parse>
    @type json
  </parse> 
</filter>
```

And got an error probally since the the type is already a json.

2.

```
<filter *>
  @type parser
  key_name log
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse> 
</filter>
```

And got this output (message "message_key" instead of the current "log"):

```
{"message": {"type": "debug", "log" :"This is the log message"} }
```

3. Tried to use the `@type record_transformer`, but the `<record>` want's a key-value and I would like to select the value only.
4. Tried to format under  with single value, but the output was:

   `{"type" => "debug", "log" => "This is the log message"}`

How can this be done? What's the best way to drop the message_key before outputing the log?

Answer (score 1):

After skimming through the fluentd plugins [here](https://www.fluentd.org/plugins) I didn't find a way to do what I wanted, so I've ended out writing my own plugin.

I'm not going to accept my answer since I hope someone will provide a better using a certified plugin.

Just in case you are desperate for a solution, here's the plugin:

```
require "fluent/plugin/filter"

module Fluent
  module Plugin
    class JsonRecordByKeyFilter < Fluent::Plugin::Filter
      Fluent::Plugin.register_filter("json_record_by_key", self)

      config_param :key

      def filter(tag, time, record)
        record[@key]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
<filter *>
  @type json_record_by_key
  key log
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same problem, but found a solution as outlined on Fluentd's website using the remove_key_name_field command:
https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/parser#remove_key_name_field

```
<filter *>
    @type parser
    key_name log
    reserve_data true
    remove_key_name_field true
    <parse>
        @type json
    </parse>
</filter>
```